# How to convert base64 image url string to blob and set to state in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I converted a base64 image url string to blob and gives me back this object

```
{size: 61683, type: 'image/png'}
```

However when I try to set the state to this blob in my react component ,it throws error of

```
Uncaught Error: `source` property is required either a string of image url or a HTMLImageElement for the image that will be edited.
```

Am I converting my base 64 image url to blob in correctly?

Comment: If the `source` property requires either a string, an image url or an HTMLImageElement you shouldn't try to give it a blob. The base64 string could be more appropriate. You could show a little more code and show what type of component/prop you are trying to set, it'd be easier to help.

Comment: Reason I'm trying to convert into a blob is because Sanity IO only accepts blobs as image file uploads and not base  64 strings